# Функция floor() как работает?

Tags: php, функции

Каким будет результат выполнения следующего фрагмента кода:

```
<?
echo floor((0.1+0.7)*10);
?>
```

И почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Будет именно 7. Потому что (0.1 + 0.7) * 10 не  будет 8, а будет 7.99(тут дальше будут любые цифры). А так как это число будет меньше 8, то результат будет 7. Почему? особенности сложение вещественных чисел.

**обновление для [[@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope)](/users/3545/alexwindhope) и всех других, кто обвинил меня в незнании математики**

Почитайте на досуге стандарт  [IEEE 754](http://www.softelectro.ru/ieee754.html) и поймите, что дробные числа не всегда могут быть представлены точно.
Здесь http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html есть хороший апплет, который показывает, как именно выглядит число в внутри, в памяти. В частности:

```
0.1 = 0.1000000014 9011612
0.2 = 0.2000000029 8023224
0.7 = 0.6999999880 7907100
```

Просуммировав все аккуратно имеем

```
0.1 + 0.7 = 0.79999998966918712
0.2 + 0.7 = 0.89999999105930324
```

То есть видим, хотя числа и близкие к желаемым, но все таки не равны им. Я правда не нашел, как реализована в пхп функция floor, думаю оно бы прояснило, почему первому не хватило, а второму уже хватило, что бы перейти через разряд.

Никогда не путайте школьную математику и процессорную.

**еще одно обновление:**

Если пойти на сайт php и почитать, что пишут о типе [float](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php), то как раз там и приводят пример, данный вопрошающим:). Всем новичкам читать до полного понимания.

Comment: А можно источник где вы прочитали про 7.9999999999 ?

Comment: точно! правильно!

Comment: Это базовые знания. php тут не при чем. Испытайте такую прогу

    <?php
    if ((0.1 + 0.7)*10 < 8) {
       print("less 8");
    } else {
       print ("8 or more");
    }
    ?>

Хотя возможно, что на некоторых платформах будет 8.

Comment: (0.1 + 0.7) * 10 

Будет  7.99? У вас по математике что было?xD

Ну сделайте

     echo (0.1 + 0.7) * 10;

Comment: При этом 


    floor((0.7+0.2)*10) == 9; // О_о
    

    floor((0.7+0.1)*10) == 7; // ну бред ппц

Comment: Еще

    floor((0.7+0.15)*10) == 8; // !!!

Comment: Нашел похожие чудеса в комментариях на офф.сайте php ^.^
 
    $int = 0.99999999999999999; // 17 чисел после точки 
    echo floor($int); // -> 1

and 

    $int = 0.9999999999999999; // 16 чисел
    echo floor($int); // -> 0 

моя плакать xD

    echo floor((0.1+0.7000000000000001)*10); // -> 8 xDDDDDD

Если это особенность сложения вещщественных чисел, то почему работает. например с `(0.7+0.2)*10`?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, скоре всего это и будет ответ. Можете преобразовать в ответ и добавить ссылку откуда вы взяли материал?

Answer (score 2):

Это действительно проблема сложение вещественных чисел, но мне всеравно непонятно почему тогда floor работает например с `0.7+0.2`, поидее тут должно выводить 8...

Ну да собственно не суть, чтобы работало и не было таких вот чудес надо писать так:

---

```
                    echo floor(round(0.7+0.1, 1)*10); // -> 8
```

---

PS: примеры в комментах смотрел [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.floor.php)

**UPD**
Насколько я понимаю здесь все намного сложнее... И мне кажется что это "плоское место" реализации функции `floor`, дабы не быть голословным и уж точно разрушить то, что написал [[[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) приведу несколько примеров:

```
floor((0.0+0.1)*10); // -> 1
floor((0.1+0.1)*10); // -> 2
floor((0.2+0.1)*10); // -> 3
floor((0.3+0.1)*10); // -> 4
floor((0.4+0.1)*10); // -> 5
floor((0.5+0.1)*10); // -> 6
floor((0.6+0.1)*10); // -> 7
floor((0.7+0.1)*10); // -> 7
floor((0.8+0.1)*10); // -> 9
```

[[[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) - да, вы правы, протестил для 4.0 - фейл :)
Но в данном случае `round($num, 1)` - решает эту проблему

PS: `round()`, в данном случае, я использовал именно для решения конкретной задачи

Comment: А как в `PHP` строятся графики? Возможно это бы ускорило решение проблемы.

Comment: не совсем понял - о каких графиках речь?

Comment: Как в математике. На координатной плоскости. В идеале должны получиться "ступеньки".

Comment: Создавайте отдельный вопрос, надо видеть ваш код и задачу в целом

Comment: вот за код вида `floor(round(0.7+0.1, 1)*10)` нужно наказывать. Да в этом случае результат совпадет с придуманным (не ожидаемым, а именно придуманным).
А если будем складывать не 0.7 и 0.1, а 0.7 и 0.18, тогда код с округлением будет делать совсем не то.

Comment: Уважаемый - у вас есть другие предложения? ну так чего вы медлите - просвятите нас

Comment: Как разруливать данную ситуацию? все зависит от того, что Вы хотите получить и какую задачу решаете. В обыденной программистской жизни редко складываются числа явно.

Comment: Обновил ответ, специально для вас :)

Comment: А давайте для затравки посмотрим ещё на вывод в диапазоне 0.1 + 4 до 0.1 + 6. Там тоже не все чисто:)
И я не говорил, что это применимо только для php. Это применимо для любого языка, который не делает программной симуляции дробных чисел.

Answer (score 0):

Округление до меньшего значения

```
0.1+0.7 = 0,8*10 = 8.
```

А floor(8) = 8

Comment: ^.^

Будет 7, я сам не пойму почему О_О

Comment: не может быть

Comment: Откройте редактор и попробуйте

Answer (score 0):

Ну чего же здесь непонятного? Язык использует не десятичные, а "двоичные" дроби. Вот если заменить 0.1 на 3/32 или на 25/256, и 0.7 заменить на что-то подобное, то результат получится совершенно предсказуемым.